# Context.Principal getting null in case of Web API call

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, .net-4.8

I have a web app developed using ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.8) and ASP.NET WEB API 2 , SQL SERVER 2016. I am using Azure AD with OpenIDConnect (authorization code flow).

In this case there is only one registration done for the web app with host name: https://www.testwebapp.com

I followed all the steps mentioned at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow and implemented the Azure AD authentication. Here goes the app details :

HOST: https://www.testwebapp.com
API Endpoint: https://www.testwebapp.com/services/api/test/current

On navigating to the URL: https://www.testwebapp.com I am redirected to Azure AD login page where I provide the credentials and I can see the claims using jwt.io . Now any call to WEB API project goes from the AngularJS app it leads to Authorization failure.

On debugging I can see the context object has no claims and hence no principal also.

Here goes the Authentication and Authorization Filer that are registered in the WebApiConfig.cs file of the API project.

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
      // Web API configuration and services
      config.Filters.Add(new SampleAuthenticationAttribute());
      config.Filters.Add(new SampleAuthorizationAttribute());
    }
}
```

SampleAuthenticationAttribute.cs:

```
public class SampleAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
    {
        private HttpAuthenticationContext _context;
        public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _context = context;
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(context.Result);
        }
    }
```

SampleAuthorizationAttribute.cs:

```
public class SampleAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            // retrieve principal and check authZ
            IPrincipal principal;
            if (!SecurityHelper.IsSecurityDisabled)
                principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as IClaimsPrincipal;
            else
                principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal;
            if (principal != null && principal.Identity != null && principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "unauthorized");
            response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Federation", "permission required."));
            actionContext.Response = response;
        }
    }
```

Here goes the overall architecture of the web app:

[image]

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance on it further.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks a bit of details how are you integrating Azure AD in your Angular app at client side (or is it all at server side?). Looks like you are not adding authorization header (bearer token) for Web API call.

If you are using [MSAL for Angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md) at client side, it has `MsalInterceptor` to automaticatically obtain token and add authorization header for your backend API calls.

Further, for backend asp.net web api, refer:

- [Quickstart: Add Microsoft identity platform sign-in to an ASP.NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp)
- [Tutorial: Add sign-in to Microsoft to an ASP.NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp)

Comment: Thanks @krishg for your response. In this implementation both frontend and API project are treated as single application using same application pool.  The API project not registered as separate application in AzureAD in this implementation and hence no bearer token is required whenever calls are made from angular to webapis. Since calls made to api project are within the same app boundary , so ideally I believe the claims should be maintained across the calls and ultimately set the principal object, which is not happening here. The app works fine in case of ADFS implementation.

Comment: Whenever calls are made from angular to webapi, how are you adding the authorization header in the http request from the browser side. I understand it might be deployed in the same application in the server side, but ultimately when app is running your client side component is running at the browser side. There is no magic which can add the header automatically unless you do something. When you say "no bearer token is required whenever calls are made from angular to webapis", that's not correct.

Comment: The same app works fine in case of ADFS implementation and in that case also I have no bearer token added to the header requests in case of any call made from angularjs to webapi. There is no separate registration for the API project in this implementation and hence I see no need to pass the bearer token in this case. Both angular and webapi together form a single app here and hence only registration done in the Azure AD

Comment: Ok, so are you by any chance serving the Angular component from an authenticated MVC view at server side? In the case, did you enable cookie auth? Not sure since you did not post the full server side startup code.

Comment: It is simple asp.net container app with frontend angular and backend asp.net web api2. Both forming one app. Yes I am following the sample :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp. There is a global.asx.cs file in the container asp.net application containing logic for Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) event.